# Converting object to a string

Tags: powershell

I have a parameter set up to allow me to display outputs to my tool:

```
Function LogWrite
{
    #This function takes the passed text and adds it to the on screen log and the external log file

    Param ([string]$logstring)
    #Get current date and time
    $now = Get-Date -Format g
    #Write to screeen
    $txb_logs.Appendtext("------------------------------------------------------------------------------ `r`n")
    $txb_logs.Appendtext("$now - $logstring `r`n")

}
```

I want to convert the below to a string?

```
$StartUp =  Get-WmiObject Win32_StartupCommand -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select Caption
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `Get-WmiObject Win32_StartupCommand -ComputerName | Select Caption` already returns multiple strings. You need to explain what you expect. You want to write every item to a new line? All on one line, with a delimiter?

Comment: I just what it ti return the caption column with every item to a new line

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `... | Select Caption` -> `... | Select Caption | Out-String`?

Comment: Out-string has worked, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just what it to return the caption column with every item to a new line

You could convert it to CSV, this would have that effect. Column name in the first line, then every item on a new line. This would adapt to any input, so you're free to select more columns, or different objects entirely.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_StartupCommand -ComputerName $ComputerName | Select Caption | ConvertTo-CSV -NoTypeInformation
```

With a slight modification, the logging function can accommodate multi-line inputs:

```
$logstring | ForEach-Object { $txb_logs.Appendtext("$now - $_`r`n") }
```

You can also play around with `Format-Table` instead of `ConvertTo-CSV`.

Comment: thank you this was also very helpful, i will play around this this, by any chance can i change the name caption when it is displayed to my log field

Comment: You can - `Select` accepts two kinds of parameters. Either (a list if) property names (`Select Caption`) or little scripts that calculate values dynamically. Scripts consist of a name and an expression. The name becomes the new "column header", the expression can be anything at all - as simple or complex as you need it: `Select @{name="New Property"; expression={$_.Caption} }`. "name" and "expression" can be abbreviated to "n" and "e". `$_` refers to the current item.

Answer (score 0):

$StartUp =  Get-WmiObject Win32_StartupCommand | Select Caption|out-string

$Startup.gettype() #This will get you the variable type.